# My Own CV Template - Help!

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, indentation, cv

I wanted to develop a hybrid of `moderncv` and article class, another CV template. I am facing difficulties. Here is my code till now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\titleformat{\section}
[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\rule[0ex]{2cm}{4pt}}
{1em}
{}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textbf{SUBHAM SONI}\\
address\\
\end{minipage}
\\[2mm]
\hrule
\section{CAREER OBJECTIVE}
\kant[2]
\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
   \tabcolsep=3pt
     \begin{tabular}{C{\dimexpr0.06\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.13\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}\toprule
\textbf{Sl. No.} & \textbf{Course} &  \textbf{Institution/ School}  & \textbf{Board/University}  &  \textbf{Year of  passing}  & \textbf{Aggregate}  \\ \midrule
1. & B.Tech. (Computer Science and Engineering)& Pondicherry  Engineering College  Puducherry & Pondicherry  University& April 2015 (pursuing) & 8.554\tnote{*} \\
2. & Higher  Secondary  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education & March 2011  & \SI{92}{\percent} \\
3. & Matriculation  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education  & March 2009 & \SI{90}{\percent} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item  \textbf{\item[*] \textbf{Cumulative grade point average up to 5\textsuperscript{th} semester}}.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\section{AREAS OF INTERESTS}
\begin{enumerate}
\item hollaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

here, why areas of interests is spread like this? Secondly, the `enumerate` or `itemize` environment, how do I shift it beyond the bar, exactly under the first letter of the section title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\centering` is a switch that causes everything inside the group following it to be centred. Remove it since you don't need it in this context - it is the cause of the alignment problem in your section title.

Moving the list environment to the right could be done using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s `leftmargin` or `wide` key-value.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertine,enumitem,kantlipsum}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{titlesec,marvosym,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable,siunitx}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\titleformat{\section}
[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\rule[0ex]{2cm}{4pt}}
{1em}
{}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\textbf{SUBHAM SONI}\\
address\\
\end{minipage}
\\[2mm]
\hrule
\section{CAREER OBJECTIVE}
\kant[2]
\section{EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION}
%\centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
   \tabcolsep=3pt
     \begin{tabular}{C{\dimexpr0.06\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.22\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                      C{\dimexpr0.13\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}\toprule
\textbf{Sl. No.} & \textbf{Course} &  \textbf{Institution/ School}  & \textbf{Board/University}  &  \textbf{Year of  passing}  & \textbf{Aggregate}  \\ \midrule
1. & B.Tech. (Computer Science and Engineering)& Pondicherry  Engineering College  Puducherry & Pondicherry  University& April 2015 (pursuing) & 8.554\tnote{*} \\
2. & Higher  Secondary  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education & March 2011  & \SI{92}{\percent} \\
3. & Matriculation  &  Petit Seminaire H.S.S. Puducherry & Tamilnadu Board of
Higher Secondary  Education  & March 2009 & \SI{90}{\percent} \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small\bfseries
      \item[*] Cumulative grade point average up to 5\textsuperscript{th} semester.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\section{AREAS OF INTERESTS}
\begin{enumerate}[wide=\dimexpr2cm+1em]
  \item hollaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\begin{enumerate}[wide=\dimexpr2cm+1em\relax]
\item hollaa
\end{enumerate}` to have the exact value?